# Setting up automatic Alerts in Cpanel

Tags: alert

How Can I setup an automatic email and sms alert notification system through cpanel ( that send me an email and/or sms whenever any of the services like apache and mysql go down.

Comment: You'll most likely need to set up a Nagios (or similar monitoring system) server. Although CPanel theoretically supports this functionality I've been unable to get it to work correctly. Also I think for SMS you need to have a compatible SMS device attached to the server

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

You will need login to WHM as a root-level user (or user root) to do this.  If you never heard of WHM, you probably do not have the necessary level of access.

Once logged into WHM as root or a root-level user, first go to "Service Manager" and ensure the services you want to receive notifications for are set to be monitored.  If not, check both checkboxes next to that service and click "save" at the bottom of that page.

Next, go to "Basic cPanel & WHM Setup" and set your contact email address, SMS and any other alert you would like to receive.

Then, go to "Contact Manager" as there are other things the cPanel&WHM server can notify you about, not just letting you know when it automatically restarts Apache or MySQL.